# APN custom notification sound issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, audio

I have remote notifications setup and working fine. I however have to play a custom sound when a notification is received (when app is NOT in foreground). I have added a file called customSound.wav to my app bundle and made sure "add to targets" is selected when i drag and drop it into my project (is this the correct way?). Server-side: the same file name has been specified as "sound": "customSound.wav". In my didReceiveRemoteNotification i am printing the userInfo dictionary and it is coming up like this:

```
aps =     
{
    alert = "Good Evening Sir";
    badge = 1;
    "custom_filed1" = 1;
    "custom_field2" = "AAA-BBB-CCC";
    name = "Sir Hubert";
    sound = default;
};
```

As you can see, sound is still "default". I am aware of the fact that if the sound specified can not be found, the default sound is played- will the sound value in the dictionary also be "default"  or it should be the file name that was specified in payload json. Is the order in which these are specified in the payload important. I have tried suggestions from other threads but not working for me. I can not show the json as I do not have access to the system at the moment. Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong ?

Comment: FWIW ANY sound (system sounds or your very own made sound) other than *default* is considered a custom sound and MUST be manually added to AppBundle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No your sound key should have the sound file name you want to play.

```
{
  aps =
  {
    alert = "message";
    sound = "sound file name.extension";
    badge = 1;
  };
}
```

eg:
    {
      aps =
      {
        alert = "message";
        sound = "tone.caf";
      };
    }

I am using this and getting successful custom alert on my notification; 
**keep sound duration as small as possible**. I did with this file format: aiff, caf

*if u want to test notification then u can try this app [https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12_)*

**I am not doing any marking of this app but it is good for testing push notification**

Comment: I meant to say that, if the system fails to play the specified sound (lets say it couldn't find the file), does the value for the key "sound" automatically change to "default" or it should still remain "customSound.wav" in the userInfo dictionary, whether there was an problem playing it or not.

Comment: is the way I am adding my custom sound to the project correct though ?

Comment: yes you are adding things correctly but the sound key should have your custom sound value or else it will take default and play it

Comment: mmhh, I'm now assuming its a server side problem then. Will check and update.

Comment: it indeed Was a server side problem. Just checked the json payload and realised 'sound' was entered twice. One with 'default' and the other with 'customSound.wav'. So the custom sound was being overridden by 'default'

Comment: what if I need to use local setting to play file. I don't need to specify it in aps. So for example my user selected needed sound for notification and then when notification will come, app will play sound based on local settings (app settings which were saved in NSUserDefault). How should looks code then?

Comment: @ mastrosov alexander :- where you able to set sound file locally in app instead of relying on server sound file..

Comment: My problem was i didn't include the ".caf" extension in the sound value. Thanks!