# How to set ios App push notfication sound with custom tone in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

In My App I need notification other than default, how it possible? I have try many code but i didn't get success. Notification send from Php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APN custom notification sound issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341919/apn-custom-notification-sound-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are sending a payload of pushnotification. You have to mention sound file name.

What ever sound you want to play, you have to add that file in project directory. Mention this file name on payload of push notification. Your sound is playing when push notification is receive.

```
{
   "aps" : 
   { 
       "alert" : "Message received from Bob" 
       "sound" : "give your file name like as opening.mp4"
   },
}
```

Feedback me it is working or not?

Comment: Check your file is added in project or not. Go to Project Target -> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resource and check your sound file is copy in this or not.

Comment: have you checked it?

Comment: It's okey bro. We are always happy to help all of you

Comment: @Wos is it possible to change sound when app in background mode?