# Xamarin iOS custom notification sound

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin, notifications

I have a Xamarin iOS app with working APNS remote notifications.
Now I want to play a custom notification sound.
I created a `notification.caf` file, added it to my Xamarin iOS Resource folder and set the action on file as `BundleResource`. Then I add the sound parameter to the `aps` field:
`{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APNs Tester.","badge":"1","sound":"notification.caf"}}`
but it does not work. I cannot find any working example online with Xamarin and iOS custom notification sounds. Any clue of why it does not work?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341919/apn-custom-notification-sound-issue

Comment: I can't see any real difference between my json dictionary and the one reported in the answer you posted. I think in my case is something related to Xamarin and placing the sound file in the right place inside the project, but I cannot find any information online about it.

Comment: I post only answers which I test myself. Unfortunately I don't use remote notification, so I cannot test. Sorry and good luck. May be somebody else can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

the .caf file tries to leave it at the root of the project, that is, at the same level of the Resources folder, not in the Resources folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1- Clean your project (just in case conflict files are there).

2- Ensure `notification.caf` is located directly in the iOS project directory (not inside internal folder). Make sure Build Action is set to `BundleResource`.

3- Add the following code to your AppDelegate.cs file:

```
public static class PushSoundManager
{
    public static void PrepareSoundsForPushIfPossible()
    {
        var pathsForResources = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User);
        if (pathsForResources.Length > 0)
        {
            var libraryPath = pathsForResources[0].Path;
            var libraryFolderPath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, Constants.SoundFolderName);
            var fileNameWithSubFolder = Constants.SoundFolderName + "/" + Constants.SoundFileName;
            var pathToStoredFileInBundle = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(fileNameWithSubFolder, Constants.SoundFilePath);
            if (pathToStoredFileInBundle != null)
            {
                var pathToFileInLibrary = Path.Combine(libraryFolderPath, Constants.SoundFileName + Constants.SoundFilePath);
                NSError returnError = null;
                NSFileAttributes attributes = null;
                NSFileManager.DefaultManager.CreateDirectory(libraryFolderPath, true, attributes, out returnError);
                if (returnError == null)
                {
                    var isExist = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(pathToFileInLibrary);
                    if (!isExist)
                    {
                        var data = NSData.FromFile(pathToStoredFileInBundle);
                        data.Save(pathToFileInLibrary, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private struct Constants
    {
        public const string SoundFolderName = "Sounds";
        public const string SoundFileName = "notification";
        public const string SoundFilePath = ".caf";
    }
}
```

4- Call `PrepareSoundsForPushIfPossible()` inside `FinishedLaunching()` method.

5- You are done. Your server side code seems already correct.